# How to set proxy in Rstudio V0.99.903 R 3.3.1 Windows?

Tags: r, proxy, rstudio

I cannot install the devtools package because I cannot set the proxy settings required by the WiFi connection that I use.

Refer to the image for the errors.

[image]

Comment: What version of R are you using? `R.version`

Answer (score 0):

create a `.Renviron`  file in  documents add

`http_proxy="http://yourproxy:8080`

`http_proxy_user=user:passwd`

`https_proxy="https://yourproxy:8080`

`https_proxy_user=user:passwd`

put the good proxy port instead of 8080 
and change Rstudio option[image]

you can check this too https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200488488-Configuring-R-to-Use-an-HTTP-or-HTTPS-Proxy

Comment: How add the username and password to it?